# Comparing the first paragraph of two documents

Tags: vba, ms-word, comparison, paragraph

I'm trying to compare the first paragraph of two files with identical contents.  One is the active file, one is a specified "Reference File."

The two ranges I'm using to store the contents keep coming up as not equal, even though using Documents.Compare to check the two files comes up with no differences.

Checking the variables as I step through it seems the two ranges' contents are identical at the time of comparison.

Apologies for inconsistent variable naming schemes.

```vb
Sub Test_Comparison()

Dim WorkingDoc As Document
Dim formatRef As Document

Dim rngDoc As Range
Dim refRnge As Range

Dim MacroViable As Boolean

Set WorkingDoc = Documents(ActiveDocument)
Set formatRef = Application.Documents.Open("[Reference FilePath]\ReferenceFile.docx", ReadOnly:=True, Visible:=False)

Set rngDoc = Documents(WorkingDoc).Paragraphs(1).Range
Set refRange = formatRef.Paragraphs(1).Range

If rngDoc.IsEqual(Range:=refRange) Then 'This is the bit not working.  The contents of the variables seems identical. What gives??
    MacroViable = True
End If

Documents("ReferenceFile.docx").Close

End Sub
```

I also tried setting the two ranges equal:

```vb
If refRange = rngDoc Then 
    MacroViable = True
End If
```

Comment: It's easy enough to compare the text of the first two paragraphs, but testing whether they're formatted the same requires more work. Word's built-in document comparison tools are well-suited to that. No VBA required. They'll also identify other differences throughout the documents.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare ranges but they won't be equal - as they are part of different documents (s. help for 'IsEqual': https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.isequal)

You have to compare the `text` of the two ranges:

```vb
If rngDoc.Text = refRange.Text Then
   MacroViable = True
End If
```